# Is it possible to call a HTTP API from Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Is it possible to hit an api from firebase cloud functions http trigger and get the response from that?

If yes please provide any sample code of it.

this is the code I'm trying :

```
exports.date = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const curl = new (require( 'curl-request' ))();
  curl.setHeaders(['Authorization: Bearer '])
    .get('url which i want to hit (api url)')
    .then(({statusCode, body, headers}) => {
      console.log(statusCode, body, headers)
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
 });
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to call HTTP APIs from Cloud Functions. What's the problem you've having?

Comment: going forward with the above code when i m hitting the function url

1.{"name":"unauthorized","message": "Your request was made with invalid credentials,"code":0,"status":401,"type":"yii\web\UnauthorizedHttpexception"}
then i relogin myself after that i tried 
2.error:could not handle the request
@ Frank van Puffelen

Comment: how can i do that plz save my day  @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: this is the error coming in firebase console
Error: Cannot find module 'curl-request'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at exports.date.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:30:19)
    
And if m installing curl-request then i m not able to deploy the cloud 
function @ Frank van Puffelen

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the question and format it. If you get an error while deploying with `curl-request` in your package.json, show what error you get.